# Charts pod: Why are extra entries added to the chart?

Tags: swift

I have a pie chart that displays data added to it
It looks like this:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var pieChart = PieChartView()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        pieChart.delegate = self               
        self.setChart()
    }
    
    func setChart() {
        var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
                
        for entry in 0..<(self.cellArr.count) {
            if self.cellArr.count > 0 {
                let dataEntry = PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(self.cellArr[entry].amount), label: String(self.cellArr[entry].type))
                entries.append(dataEntry)
            }
        }
        updateSorting(values: entries)
    }
    
    func updateSorting(values: [ChartDataEntry]){
        let dataSet = PieChartDataSet(entries: values, label: "")
        let data = PieChartData(dataSets: [dataSet])
        
        dataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
        pieChart.data = data
        pieChart.notifyDataSetChanged()        
    }
}
```

The problem is in the entries variable, which is located in the setChart function. I need to work with it outside the function, but if I put it in a class -

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var pieChart = PieChartView()
    var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = [] // <------------ !!!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        pieChart.delegate = self               
        self.setChart()
    }
}
```

Then the chart will start displaying extra values

An illustrative example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OajJ6.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL59Z.png)

In the first screenshot, entries is in a function, in the second it is already behind it

I tried to set breakpoints and look at the for loop, but I still don’t understand why it happens that the array adds old data to new ones with each iteration

Comment: When do you call `setChart`? By the way, `if self.cellArr.count > 0 {` doesn't really make sense. Think about it, if you're already in the `for` loop, when will the `self.cellArr.count` ever be `0`??

Comment: @Alexander `setChart` is called in the `viewWillAppear` function, this is shown in the code below
When `cellArr` becomes zero the chart is simply not displayed. But I already removed the condition, yes it was superfluous

Comment: think about what would happen if your view appeared, then disappeared, then appeared again? It would keep accumulating more and more points into the same `cellArr` (which is never reset). Also, have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/77986d5b1d2d2d74637bba3050ffc2c8

Comment: @Alexander won't accumulate, i have remove functions from both cellArr and chart, they are related

Comment: Well then it looks like you're not clearing them at all the right times.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, you're right, I revised my code, I started doing a cleanup every time I call setChart, now everything works!
Can you post your link to the github with this code not as a comment, but as an answer so that I mark it as correct?

Comment: Manually clearing it in response to certain events seems error-prone. You're pretty likely to forget some. I would suggest just overwriting the array whenever you update it, instead of clearing and appending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're calling `setChart` from `viewWillAppear`, you'll be appending to many items in your array (if the view appears/disappears in a single session). You need to clear the variables appropriately, or just overwrite them entirely.

---

Unrelated, but you can greatly simplify this for loop code:

Start:

```swift
func setChart1() {
    var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
            
    for entry in 0..<(self.cellArr.count) {
        if self.cellArr.count > 0 {
            let dataEntry = PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(self.cellArr[entry].amount), label: String(self.cellArr[entry].type))
            entries.append(dataEntry)
        }
    }
    updateSorting(values: entries)
}
```

Remove useless `if` statement:

```swift
func setChart2() {
    var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
            
    for entry in 0..<(self.cellArr.count) {
        let dataEntry = PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(self.cellArr[entry].amount), label: String(self.cellArr[entry].type))
        entries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    updateSorting(values: entries)
}
```

Replace manually constructed range of indices with a simple `Array.indices`:

```swift
func setChart3() {
    var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
            
    for entry in self.cellArr.indices { // "entry" is a total misnomer. It's not an entry, it's an index that can be used to get an entry
        let dataEntry = PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(self.cellArr[entry].amount), label: String(self.cellArr[entry].type))
        entries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    updateSorting(values: entries)
}
```

Realize that you don't even need the indices, you only actually care about the values themselves:

```swift
func setChart4() {
    var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
            
    for entry in self.cellArr {
        let dataEntry = PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(entry.amount), label: String(entry.type))
        entries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    updateSorting(values: entries)
}
```

Inline local variable (its name adds no useful information):

```swift
func setChart5() {
    var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
            
    for entry in self.cellArr {
        entries.append(PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(entry.amount), label: String(entry.type)))
    }
    updateSorting(values: entries)
}
```

Notice that this is just a `map` operation:

```swift
func setChart6() {
    var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = self.cellArr.map { entry in
        PieChartDataEntry(value: Double(entry.amount), label: String(entry.type)))
    }
    updateSorting(values: entries)
}
```

`entries` can now be immutable, and can use type inference:

```swift
func setChart7() {
    let entries = self.cellArr.map { PieChartDataEntry(value: Double($0.amount), label: String($0.type))) }
    updateSorting(values: entries)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the array of `entries` into a class and cleared it in the `setChart7` function

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    var pieChart = PieChartView()

    var entries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.setChart()
    }

    func setChart7() {
        entries.removeAll()
        let entries = self.cellArr.map { PieChartDataEntry(value: Double($0.amount), label: String($0.type))) }
        updateSorting(values: entries)
    }
}
```